# Is the ceiling of n^(0.5) is still big oh of n^0.5?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I know that for f(n) to be O(g(n)) we have to find a constant c > 0 and n<sub>0</sub> such that f(n) ≤ c⋅g(n)
whenever n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

So what I am thinking is that if we take c to be 2 for example and n<sub>0</sub> to be 1 it seems to me that n<sup>0.5</sup> is O(n<sup>0.5</sup>). Am I right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science and should be asked on [cs.se]

Comment: `so what i am thinking is that if we take c to be 2 for example we and n0 to be 1 it seems to me that n^(0.5) is O(n^0.5) am i right ?` Yes.

Comment: Adding a constant will never change the big-O complexity of anything. Finaggling it to multiplication by a coefficient sort of seems to be missing the point.

Comment: @Potatoswatter But you need to work with constants to prove the big-O complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but it is easier to see what is going on if you make n0 very large, say n0=10^6, Then n^0.5 >= 1000, and the difference between n^0.5 and ceil(n^0.5) is <= 1, so is obviously covered by c=2, and in fact is obviously trivial. As Potatoswatter points out, as long as f(n) is increasing, you can make n large enough that a change of a constant is obviously trivial, no matter what the constant.